# Breaking a long URL to several line in javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, javadoc

If I'm using a piece of code or resources fetch from etc internet I like to point this out in class or function documentation and also provide a link to the original source. However, I would also like to stick to max 80 chars per line principle when writing code for better readability. Is there a way to parse a long URL in source to multiple lines and still maintain the original address as usable when using the javadoc in IDE like Eclipse? And with usable I mean that clicking the URL in javadoc tooltip opens the correct page.

For example, how would you format the following:

```
/**
 * Class to do some cool stuff
 * Original source: 
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/and-huge-amouts-of-URL-address-which-does-not-fit-to-80-chars
 */
public class ExampleClass {

}
```

Comment: I don't think so. Use a link shortener, maybe? On SO, fwiw, you can use the URL just up to the question id. For instance, this question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056517.

Comment: *"I would also like to stick to max 80 chars per line principle when writing code for better readability"* It a principle, not a law that will send you to jail for violating it. Long URLs are not readable. If you use a link shortener, the link becomes totally obscure, i.e. not readable. So, what exactly are you trying to make readable? So what if the javadoc source will have a long line with a URL that's not readable anyway? Just make the compiled javadoc readable, like [philantrovert showed you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41056619/5221149).

Comment: I know its not a law, but sometimes one encounters a thing like this and I'm the kinda guy who gets irritated and is curious to find a workaround :) But I'll settle for shortened links for now. Thanks guys!

Comment: This becomes relevant if your team uses something like Checkstyle to enforce code standards like line length.  Since the line cannot be split, an override comment or configuration will be needed to address the warning.  In this example, I added `<property name="ignorePattern" value="^ *\* *@see.+$"/>` to the `lineLength` Checkstyle configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to use a URL shortener you can surround your url with `<pre></pre>` tags as follows:

```
/**
 * Class to do some cool stuff
 * Original source: 
 * <pre>
 * See <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/
   and-huge-amouts-of-URL-address-which-does-not-fit-to-80-chars">NameOfyourLink</a>
 * </pre>
 */
```

This will satisfy checkstyle for example and let you keep your original URL.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution I found is to just break the lines and make sure the successive ones follow exactly the URL (not have any other character in between).

For example:

```
/**
* Link to <a href="https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#
startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)">startForeground(..)</a>
*/
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  It also works well with `@see`.  The only disadvantage I see is that the missing ` *  ` on the third line looks a bit ugly.

Having said that, I tried the accepted answer (using `<pre>` tags), and it seems that you need to remove the ` *  ` for the URL to work properly with that too.  Additionally, as a side effect of the accepted answer, the `<pre>` tags can affect the Javadoc formatting which is not the case with this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead you can use the following

```
@see <a href = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/and-huge-amouts-of-URL-address-which-does-not-fit-to-80-chars"> SO Link </a>
```

and It will be rendered as:

> **See Also:**
>       [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/and-huge-amouts-of-URL-address-which-does-not-fit-to-80-chars)

Source : [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html)

Comment: This is a neat way to shorten the link which the user sees in tooltip, but in the original source the link still exceeds the 80 char limit.

Comment: Then I think the only go-to solution would be a URL shortener.